# Find Total Size of Subarrays In Array

Tags: mongodb

How can i find total subarrays size(for this example it is 5) ?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0cb")
    "modules" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "Store CM",
            "_id" : ObjectId("54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0d6"),
            "documents" : [ 
               {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0ce"),
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0cc"),
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "title" : "Store CM 2",
            "_id" : ObjectId("54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0d6"),
            "documents" : [ 
               {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0ct"),
                },
                               {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0c1"),
                },
                               {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0c7"),
                }
            ]
        },  
    ]
}
```

Comment: In which language do you want a solution? JavaScript?

Comment: Which array are you talking about? `modules` or `documents`. Please edit your question accordingly to show the sample output that you need.

Comment: I need mongo query solution or aggregation.

Comment: @mTuran Can you provide some more details on what you're looking for? I don't see how 6 would be the right answer for any array size query.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I'm sorry my mistake. Right count is 5.

Answer (score 1):

This function should walk all arrays in an object and return the total amount of arrays in the object.

```
db.runCommand( {
  eval: function countArrays(object){ 

   var totalLength = 0;
   var arr = Object.keys(object);
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(object[arr[i]] instanceof Array){
            totalLength += countArrays(object[arr[i]]);

        }
        else if (object[arr[i]] instanceof Object)
        {
            totalLength += countArrays(object[arr[i]]);
        }
   }
   return totalLength;
}

args: [ reference to db-object]
}
);
```

MongoDB allow Javascript functions to be run via `eval`. If you provide object.modules as argument to the function, this function should return 5.

Comment: Thanks but is there any way to do it with mongo query or aggregation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of an array field by using the [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size) operator in an aggregation pipeline, so you can get the total count of `documents` elements per doc like this:

```javascript
db.test.aggregate([
    // Duplicate the docs, one per modules array element
    {$unwind: '$modules'},
    // Regroup on _id, summing up the size of each doc's documents array
    {$group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        totalsize: {$sum: {$size: '$modules.documents'}}
    }}
])
```

Output:

```javascript
[ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0cb"),
        "totalsize" : 5
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: new ObjectId('54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0cb') }},
    { $unwind: '$modules' },
    { $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        modulesLength: { $sum: 1 },
        documentsLength: {$sum: {$size: '$modules.documents'}}
    }}
]).exec(function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```